# How to make the concat operator subscribe to an array of Observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have a situation where a service returns a number of Observables in an array. I need to subscribe to them in such a way where one is subscribed after the previous is complete.

I have done a similar thing before with the `concat` operator, and it works great, but it only works if you put the observables as the parameters of the `concat` signature like this. `concat(obs1, obs2, obs3)` But if you have `concat([obs1, obs2, obs3])` the behaviour changes completely.

```
concat(
        of(1, 2, 3).pipe(delay(3000)),
        of(4, 5, 6).pipe(delay(3000)),
      ).pipe(
        toArray()
      )
      .subscribe((v) => {
        // Gets called after 6 seconds containing all the data as number[].
        console.log(v);
      });

      const obs = [of(1, 2, 3).pipe(delay(3000)), of(4, 5, 6).pipe(delay(3000))];

      concat(obs).pipe(
        toArray()
      )
      .subscribe((v) => {
        // I want to get the same behaviour as before, but instead of v bein number[]
        // it comes as an Observable<number>[]
        console.log(v);
      });
```

How can I make it so the concat function works the same way as the code example? Having only the resulting data as the subscription callback.

Comment: How about using the `merge` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const obs = [of(1, 2, 3).pipe(delay(3000)), of(4, 5, 6).pipe(delay(3000))];

concat(...obs).pipe(toArray()).subscribe((v) => console.log(v);});
```

Comment: Hey this worked perfect, I wonder why using the default array notation triggers that weird behaviour. I looked into the [`concat`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat) documentation and it shows that this is the expected behaviour but does not explain why.

Comment: It make me confused too, but i really dont think the `Type:Array` in the document mean it take an `Array<Observable>` as parameter.